# How to relate Opportunity Line Items to Contract LIne Items (in Service Contract)

Tags: opportunity-lineitem, service

I am quite a novice in Flow, and would like advice. My business case is to Relate Opportunity line items with Contract Line Items (in Service Contract object).

When my Opportunity is closed/won with related Opportunity products, a Service Contract is created with related Contract Line items related to Opportunity Line Items.

Here are my process steps :

Get the parent Opportunity record that triggered the process : Id Equals to OpportunityId (variable)

Create a Draft Service Contract record using Opportunity records values : Create_Service_contract

Set Fields

- AccountId <-- Opportunity from Get_Opportunity.AccountId
- StartDate <-- Opportunity from Get_Opportunity.CloseDate
- Status__c <-- Active

Get Opportunity LIne Items (Get_Opportunity_Line_Items) : OpportunityId (Opportunity Product) Equals to OpportunityId
In Opportunity product (object) : OpportunityId Equals OpportunityId

Loop through Products (Loop_through_Products) : Collection Variable {!Get_Opportunity_Line_Items)

First Assignment : Assign Service Contract ID to Opportunity Line Items : Loop_through_Products Equals to Service ContractId from Create_Service_contract
Loop-through_products Equals Service Contractid from Create_Service_contract

Update Contract Line items (Variable Collection) to Opportunity Line Items
Update Record : Variable ContractLineItemCollection

Could you help me figure out what is wrong in my Flow or give me advice ?

Many thanks for your help!!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. What exactly is not working? (use [edit].  A screenshot of your Flow would be helpful. Also, did you set `ServiceContract.Pricebook2Id` before adding the line items?

Comment: Thank you @cropredy for your reply! What is the use of ServiceContract.Pricebook2Id? I'm not sure to understand.

Comment: My business use case is to create automatically a Service Contract record when my opportunity is closed/won and relate the opportunity line items with Contract Line Items (from Service Contract object) and related opportunity records like Account > Company Name, Opportunity Owner etc

Comment: `ContractLineItem.PricebookEntryId` is required and this makes `ServiceContract.Pricebook2Id` required. Since your `OpportunityLineItem` presumably has `PricebookEntryId`s, this means your Service Contract records must mirror that